# which version of windows seven is better?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What edition of Windows 7 should I purchase and install?](https://superuser.com/questions/91874/what-edition-of-windows-7-should-i-purchase-and-install)

I am trying to purchase a windows seven, but I find out there are different editions for windows seven?? anybody has any idea which one is better ???

Comment: They're all great: http://xkcd.com/528/

Answer (score 2):

Different versions make sense for different people depending on what you plan on using it for.  You can compare the features of the different versions using the link below.  Scroll about halfway down the page when you get there.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/compare/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The version with the most features is Enterprise. That is not available without a volume license though. The version with the most features that is readily available for consumers is Ultimate.

Most home users are fine with Home Premium though.